# Configure Jest for Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

According to various guides on the web configuring Jest for Angular is as easy as [this](https://www.lambda-it.ch/blog/post/using-jest-with-angular):

```
ng new jest-test
cd jest-test
npm i -D jest jest-preset-angular
```

Modify *package.json*:

```
"test": "jest",
[...]
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./src/setup-jest.ts"
},
```

*setup-jest.ts*:

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';
```

When running `npm test` I keep running into this error, though:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

jest-test/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
                                                                                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

I have tried countless variations of configuring the app that I found on th e web, all yielding this error message.

Let me know if I need to supply additional information.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Angular CLI [this](https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/jest) library would be very helpful.
It will allow you to keep your workspace clear of boilerplate code related to Jest setup and also run your tests with Angular CLI (`ng test`).
This will also save you the trouble of configuring Jest.

As for your specific error, it is most probably related to your *tsconfig.spec.json*. Have you changed the `module` field to `commonjs`? This is required to make Jest work.

For more details read [this](https://codeburst.io/angular-6-ng-test-with-jest-in-3-minutes-b1fe5ed3417c) article.

*Disclaimer: I'm the owner of this library.*

Comment: With Angular 8 after following the suggested steps in the article I still get this error:  app.component.spec.ts:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
                                                                                                    ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {  "module": "commonjs" is set

Comment: Please open an issue on Github with minimal reproduction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a couple of weeks ago following this [article](https://www.xfive.co/blog/testing-angular-faster-jest/).

It went smooth but I decided to not move from Jasmine/Karma to Jest.
The reasons:

- I need to run UTs on multiple real browsers and Jest can't do it. (Read the discussion on the [Jest Repository](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/848)
- I can use Jasmin to write also e2e tests using Protractor or Selenium-Webdriver

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed this article as well. They basically do the same setup. Did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ionic, and was looking to get things going with Ionic 4 and Angular 6 with Jest.  I found [this blog post from Brian Love](https://brianflove.com/2018/05/26/angular-jest-testing/), followed it, and was able to get the basics up.  As a side note, I configure my Jest in an external file, and the contents are shown here as I did change a few things, but have my tests running now with Jest under Angular 6.

```
module.exports = {
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/coverage/",
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules",
        "test-config",
        "<rootDir>/src/app/interfaces",
        "jestGlobalMocks.ts",
        ".module.ts",
        "<rootDir>/src/app/main.ts"
    ],
    },
    preset: "jest-preset-angular",
    roots: ['src'],
    setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: "<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts",
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/(?!(@ionic-native|@ionic|angularfire2)/)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, after starting a new Angular project from scratch, I was configuring it to use Jest for Unit tests. I built up the configuration by looking at an old project of mine but having it work for Angular 13 and Jest 27.

I made the following configuration steps. Not all of them may be necessary, but to have a complete list of what I did, here you go.

1. Add to `package.json` to `scripts`:

   ```
   "test": "jest  --coverage --config ./jest.config.js"
   ```
2. Remove all `karma` dependencies from `package.json`.
3. Add to `package.json` to `devDependencies` (you may get newer ones, those were the latest versions to me):

   ```
   "@babel/core": "~7.16.12",
   "@babel/preset-env": "~7.16.11",
   "@babel/preset-typescript": "~7.16.7",
   "@types/jest": "~27.4.0",
   "babel-jest": "~27.4.6",
   "jest": "~27.4.7",
   "jest-preset-angular": "~11.1.0",
   "ts-jest": "~27.1.3",
   ```
4. Add to `tsconfig.spec.ts` under `compilerOptions / types`:

   ```
   "jest",
   "node"
   ```
5. Remove from `tsconfig.spec.ts` under `files`:

   ```
   "src/test.ts"
   ```
6. Remove file `src/test.ts`.
7. Added `jest.config.js`:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
     cacheDirectory: "<rootDir>/jest/cache",
     clearMocks: true,
     collectCoverage: true,
     coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/jest/report",
     globals: {
       "ts-jest": {
         tsconfig: "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
       }
     },
     moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "json"],
     preset: "jest-preset-angular",
     setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"],
     "transform": {
       "^.+\\.(ts|js)$": "ts-jest"
     },
     verbose: true
   }
   ```
8. Added `babel.config.js`:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     presets: [
       ['@babel/preset-env',
         {
           targets: {
             node: 'current'
           }
         }
       ],
       '@babel/preset-typescript',
     ]
   };
   ```
9. Run `npm i` and you're (hopefully) good to go.